# Need a concept on fetching data with HQL while three or more tables are in use

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

A small briefing on what I am trying to do.

I have three tables Content(contentId, body, timeofcreation), ContentAttachmentMap(contentId, attachmentId) and Attachment(attachmentId, resourceLocation).

The reason I adopted to create the mapping table because in future application the attachment can also be shared with different content.

Now I am using HQL to get data. My objectives is as follows:

1. Get All contents with/without Attachments

I have seen some examples in the internet like you can create an objective specific class (not POJO) and put the attribute name from the select statement within its constructor and the List of that Class object is returned.

For e.g. the HQL will be `SELECT new com.mydomain.myclass(cont.id, cont.body)` ..... and so on.

In my case I am looking for the following `SELECT new com.mydomain.contentClass(cont.id, cont.body, List<Attachment>`) FROM ...`. Yes, I want to have the resultList contain contentid, contentbody and List of its Attachments as a single result List item. If there are no attachments then it will return (cont.id, contentbody, null).

Is this possible? Also tell me how to write the SQL statements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I feel you are using Hibernate in a fundamentally wrong way. You should use Hibernate to view your domain entity, not to use it as exposing the underlying table.

You don't need to have that `contentClass` special value object for all these. Simply selecting the Content entity serves what you need.

I think it will be easier to have actual example.

In your application, you are not seeing it as "3 tables", you should see it as 2 entities, which is something look like:

```
@Entity
public class Content {
  @Id
  Long id;

  @Column(...)
  String content;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name="ContentAttachmentMap")
  List<Attachment> attachments;
}

@Entity
public class Attachment {
  @Id
  Long id;

  @Column(...)
  String resourceLocation
}
```

And, the result you are looking for is simply the result of HQL of something like

`from Content where attachments IS EMPTY`

I believe you can join fetch too in order to save DB access:

`from Content c left join fetch c.attachments where c.attachments IS EMPTY`